# Flutter: How to Get the Number of Text Lines

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to Get the Number of Text Lines
In our Flutter project, we need to determine if the number of lines of text exceeds 3, then we will display a prompt message. How can we use the code to implement it?

Comment: Should that happen on user input or when showing a `Text` widget to the user?

Comment: Do you mean `Text` or `TextField` input ?

Comment: you can use maxLines property of texfiled to limit the same

Comment: i used Text(),and want get the number of Text() Lines

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you simply want to know how many intrinsic lines the text contains, you can do a simple

```
final numLines = '\n'.allMatches(yourText).length + 1;
```

However, I guess you're more interested in the number of lines that are actually being displayed visually.
Here, things get a little more complicated, because you need to know the available space (the `BoxConstraints`) in order to calculate how many lines the text needs.
To do that, you can use a `LayoutBuilder` to delay the widget building and a `TextPainter` to do the actual calculation:

```
return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  final span = TextSpan(text: yourText, style: yourStyle);
  final tp = TextPainter(text: span, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
  tp.layout(maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth);
  final numLines = tp.computeLineMetrics().length;

  if (numLines > 3) {
    // TODO: display the prompt message
    return ColoredBox(color: Colors.red);
  } else {
    return Text(yourText, style: yourStyle);
  }
});
```

I extracted some of the code from the [`auto_size_text` pub package](https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text/blob/master/lib/src/auto_size_text.dart), which might also be interesting to you:
It sizes its text so it fits in the given space.

Anyhow, be careful when displaying the prompt:
Your widget's `build` method may be called several times per second, resulting in multiple prompts being displayed simultaneously.

Note: The `computeLineMetrics()` function was added after the initial version of the answer. That's why a previous version of this answer used a `TextPainter(text: span, maxLines: 3)` and then checked if `tp.didExceedMaxLines`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual number of lines if `maxLInes` is infinity?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no official API for that, but there are some hacky ways to do that for sure. For example, you could divide `tp.height` by the `fontSize * fontScale`, but I'm not sure that works reliably. Or you could increase `maxLines` until it fits (see https://github.com/leisim/auto_size_text/issues/14 for a performance discussion about a similar topic).

Comment: The following post discusses the lack of this feature in more detail: https://medium.com/@studymongolian/my-first-disappointment-with-flutter-5f6967ba78bf

Answer (score 18):

***Update**: this answer is here for historical purposes. See [my updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57738556/3681880) for a much easier solution.*

---

If you have a `TextPainter` object and you have already called `layout`, then you can get the number of lines by selecting everything and calling `getBoxesForSelection`. Each box is the size of the line.

```
TextSelection selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: text.length);
List<TextBox> boxes = textPainter.getBoxesForSelection(selection);
int numberOfLines = boxes.length;
```

Here is an example:

```
final text = 'My text line.\nThis line wraps to the next.\nAnother line.';
```

[image]

```
print(numberOfLines); // 4
```

Unfortunately, this fails if there is a mix of bidirectional text:

```
final text = 'My text line.\nThis كلمة makes more boxes.\nAnother line.';
```

[image]

```
print(numberOfLines); // 6
```

This could be overcome by only counting the boxes that along one edge. If you notice the data from above, there are only four boxes that have an edge at 0.0.

```
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(0.0, 0.2, 171.8, 36.0, TextDirection.ltr)
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(0.0, 36.5, 68.4, 72.3, TextDirection.ltr)
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(68.4, 38.2, 111.5, 75.0, TextDirection.rtl)
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(111.5, 36.5, 299.9, 72.3, TextDirection.ltr)
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(0.0, 77.2, 92.2, 113.0, TextDirection.ltr)
flutter: TextBox.fromLTRBD(0.0, 113.2, 179.7, 149.0, TextDirection.ltr)
```

I wish there were a `TextPainter.numberOfLines` method, but I haven't found it.

Comment: Suragch, thanks for the article and the code you put together. For my own testing purposes, I pulled out your snippet into a StatelessWidget to make it easier to experiment. https://gist.github.com/venkatd/86c0185e38d5a482c2f04ecf5aeb057b

Comment: it did not work in flutter web if you text without \n in text.

Answer (score 17):

It is now easy to find the number of lines in a paragraph:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

List<ui.LineMetrics> lines = textPainter.computeLineMetrics();
int numberOfLines = lines.length;
```

Notes

- `computeLineMetrics` must be called after layout.
- I had another answer which I am keeping for historical purposes because I need to link to it in an explanation of the change.

See also

- [Flutter line metrics](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-line-metrics-fd98ab180a64)

Comment: Not sure if it's related but is there any method on Flutter that can get text offset of a line in Flutter or get the String value of text inside a TextBox? Similar to getLinexxx on Android (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#getLineStart(int))

Comment: @LongPhan. I had the same question before, too. It's possible but not super convenient. In the future they may add that info to LineMetrics, but for now see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943994/how-to-get-the-raw-text-from-a-flutter-textbox) and my answer to it.

Comment: Thank u. I think we can propose it to Flutter team.

Comment: @LongPhan, [they know about it.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35994#issuecomment-525977419)

Answer (score 8):

I just got backed by this code , hence this is how I validate whether it crosses the maxlines or not

```
var text="Clita takimata dolor diam magna aliquyam et sed dolores sadipscing. Sed ut 
diam rebum labore sadipscing sit amet, diam labore.";
final span=TextSpan(text:text);
final tp =TextPainter(text:span,maxLines: 3,textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width); // equals the parent screen width
print(tp.didExceedMaxLines);
//false for maxlines 3
//true for maxlines 1
```

Comment: it did not work in flutter web remains always false even a single line

Answer (score -1):

just place property  maxLines: null, and TextInputAction.done, if you want restrict new lines to a particular limit count "\n" .