# How to count how many lines in a textfield?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

I need to know how many lines in textfield that have been input by the user. Is there any syntax for doing it? Here is my code. Appears "only static members can be accessed in initializer"

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Page1 createState() => Page1();
}

class Page1 extends State<MyCustomForm> {

  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  String change = '';

  final numLines = '\n'.allMatches(change).length + 1; //appears Only static members can be accessed in initializer

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: 26,
                  controller: myController,
                  onChanged: (String e){
                    setState(() {
                      change = e;
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add some amount of code which you have done

Comment: here is my code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find your answer here 
[flutter-how-to-get-the-number-of-text-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091055/flutter-how-to-get-the-number-of-text-lines)

Next time please make sure you do some search on previous questions before your create duplicates. Thank You

**EDIT**

Seems you are new to flutter. You can't use the function there

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Page1 createState() => Page1();
}

class Page1 extends State<MyCustomForm> {

  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  int numLines = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: 26,
                  controller: myController,
                  onChanged: (String e){
                     setState((){
                         numLines = '\n'.allMatches(e).length + 1;
                     })
                  },
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well, I already checked that one and still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What is your problem? You can get the line count from source I mentioned.

Comment: when I put  

final numLines = '\n'.allMatches(yourText).length + 1;

It appears

"only static members can be accesed in initializers"

I don't have any idea what should I fix.

Comment: update your question with the code. I think you have entered the code in a wrong place.

Comment: @ Praneeth Dhanushka Fernando Thank you so much for your help, I understand now. Yes I just started flutter 1 week ago. I get the numLine, now I want to put it on text. 

new Text(numLine),

But still dont get it right.

Comment: I updated answer with a variable. If its working mark my answer as correct